# Session Cookie Management - Cookie Lifetime

Tags: cache, cookie, sessions

Has anyone ever set the lifetime to 3 days / 259200? I know the standard is 86400.

Would this overload cache/sessions? I'm currently not using redis or and memcache/session management. I have a feeling it would be much more practical to change this setting if I was utilizing

Right now my session save is to the db:  `<session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>`

Should i save it to a file instead?

Pros and Cons?

Answer (score 2):

if the longer lifetime could cause problems depends on the amount of people going to your website and so creating new sessions.

db has the advantage, that you can have the sessions distributed between several app servers (also redis or memcache could do this for you).

But, having the session set to files, should actually be faster if your not using a session handler like redis or memcache.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the information. What about just setting the cookie lifetime to 259200 and doing nothing else? The website is very busy.

Comment: that depends i think (best answer in programming questions;)) you could try how long it takes to select a single session from you database to figure it out

Comment: So pretty much, you're thinking it's not a great idea unless I switch to storing the sessions to a file?

Comment: How would i go about selecting a single session from the database?

Comment: i don't have a database right now, but it should be something like this: select * from core_session where session_id like "your_session_id". Not sure about this, look up the correct colum names first